# Не работает Wifi в Arch Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux

Поставил на ноутбук последний Arch Linux. Все заработало нормально, но никак получается правильно настроить адатер для подключения к WiFi. Стандартные действия не помогли. Предполагаю, что проблемы с драйвером.

**ifconfig -a**

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::44ea:b05b:aa45:e3f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:ab:3a:5e:42:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 39191  bytes 33049147 (31.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28836  bytes 5155732 (4.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 21  bytes 1631 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21  bytes 1631 (1.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**lspci -v**

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at c4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-41-ff-ff-f8-b0-10
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Нет у вас никаких  проблем с драйверами!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт

```
pacman -S broadcom-wl
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то `ip a` в Arch, а не `ifconfig -a`. Используйте NetworkManager в нем есть `nmcli` и `nmtui`.

Comment: Это не ответ - это комментарий. Давать ссылку без пояснений - плохой стиль, ссылки могут измениться и Ваша информация станет бесполезной. Есть смысл привести Ваш ответ к виду пригодному для SO,  что благотворно отразиться на Вашей репутации.

Comment: Я учту Ваше пожелание.

Answer (score 0):

```
pacman -S wpa_supplicant iw
iw dev
ip link set up [if_name]
ip address show 

wpa_passphrase SSID password > SSID.conf
wpa_supplicant -B -i if_name -c SSID.conf
dhcpcd if_name
```

Comment: "iw dev" - пустой список

"iwconfig"  - везде "no wireless extensions"